# How to add Malayalam unicode font in Websites

Tags: css, unicode, fonts

I have to develop a website having contents in Malayalam. Anyone please help me in doing this.I tried this code but didnt work.

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'meeraregular';
    /*src: url('font/meera-webfont.eot');*/
    src: url('meera-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('meera-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('meera-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('meera-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('meera-webfont.svg#meeraregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
.font{ font-family: 'meeraregular';}
```

Comment: step 1: stop using all those different formats: everything supports WOFF, which *wraps* opentype fonts byte-for-byte so you don't need the ttf/otf sources; `eot` is no longer relevant because MS abandoned IE8 and below, and `svg` isn't even a supported font format anymore. With that simplification, just with `.woff`, see what your browser's console and network tabs say. Any 404s? And before you respond with a comment: don't leave a comment, update your post with that information instead.

Comment: @Lekshmi have you found solution ?

Comment: still the same issue...Is there any settings in safari for this ?? All my fonts look blurry not only malayalam fonts

Comment: Hi, I solved the unicode issue.. Now In my site, the fonts work well in all major browsers from localhost including safari, but when I've uploaded it to server it behaves differently(blur) in safari. In css:

@font-face{ font-family:'NotoSansMalayalam-Regular'; src: url('font/NotoSansMalayalam-Regular.ttf')format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }

.font-m{font-family:'NotoSansMalayalam-Regular'; }

I don't know what I am doing wrong please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I have build the `@font-face` with available font file extensions.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'meeraregular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://smc.org.in/downloads/fonts/meera/Meera.woff2?v=7.0) format('woff2'), url(https://smc.org.in/downloads/fonts/meera/Meera.woff?v=7.0) format('woff'), url(https://smc.org.in/downloads/fonts/meera/Meera.ttf?v=7.0) format('truetype');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0D01-0D7F, U+200C-U+200D, U+25CC;
}
.font {
  font-family: 'meeraregular';
}
```

```html
<p class="font">കുഞ്ഞേടത്തിയെ തന്നെയല്ലോ ഉണ്ണിയ്ക്കെന്നെന്നുംമേറെയിഷ്ടം പൊന്നേ പോലത്തെ നെറ്റിയിലുണ്ടല്ലോ മഞ്ഞൾ വരക്കുറി ചാന്ദുപൊട്ടും ഈറൻമുടിയിലെള്ളണ്ണ മണം ചിലനേരമാ തുമ്പത്തൊരു പൂവും കയ്യിലൊരറ്റ കുപ്പിവള മുഖം കണ്ടാൽ കാവിലെ ദേവി തന്നെ മടിയിലുരുത്തീട്ട് മാറോട് ചേത്തിട്ടു
  മണി മണി പോലെ കഥപറയും ആനേടെ, മയിലിന്റെ, ഒട്ടകത്തിന്റെയും ആരും കേൾക്കാത്ത കഥപറയും</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
<style>
 @import url('https://smc.org.in/fonts/meera.css'); body { font-family: 'Meera', sans-serif; } 
</style>

<body>
 കുഞ്ഞേടത്തിയെ തന്നെയല്ലോ ഉണ്ണിയ്ക്കെന്നെന്നുംമേറെയിഷ്ടം പൊന്നേ പോലത്തെ നെറ്റിയിലുണ്ടല്ലോ മഞ്ഞൾ വരക്കുറി ചാന്ദുപൊട്ടും ഈറൻമുടിയിലെള്ളണ്ണ മണം ചിലനേരമാ തുമ്പത്തൊരു പൂവും കയ്യിലൊരറ്റ കുപ്പിവള മുഖം കണ്ടാൽ കാവിലെ ദേവി തന്നെ മടിയിലുരുത്തീട്ട് മാറോട് ചേത്തിട്ടു മണി മണി പോലെ കഥപറയും ആനേടെ, മയിലിന്റെ, ഒട്ടകത്തിന്റെയും ആരും കേൾക്കാത്ത കഥപറയും 
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.